# ng-class not working inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I tried creating a directive:

```
app.directive('barsCurrent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('value', function (newValue) {
                // value attribute has changed, re-render              
                var value = Number(newValue);
                var dval = value / 3;
                element.children().remove();
                while (dval > 0) {
                    element.append('<div id="bar" ng-class="{true: 'greater',false: 'less'}[charge.current >= charge.max]" style="float:left; color:green; height: 17px;margin-top:7px;background-color:green;">.</div>')
                    dval--;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and ng-class is not working. Any thoughts why it is not working or can you suggest another way to do it?

This is my controller:

```
app.controller("controller", function ($scope) {
    $scope.chargeability = [{ date: '15-Sep-13', max: 100, current: 100 },
    { date: '30-Sep-13', max: 60, current: 50 },
    { date: '15-Oct-13', max: 80, current: 20 }];
    $scope.ytd = 122;
});
```

and here is the html body:

```
<div ng-repeat="charge in chargeability">
 <bars-current style="z-index:999999;" value="{{charge.current}}">current:{{charge.current}}</bars-current>
<div style="clear:both;height:6px;"></div>
```

I would like to accomplish this style in the ng-class:

```
<style>
.greater {
    color:#D7E3BF;
    background-color:#D7E3BF;
}
.less {
    color:#E5B9B5;
    background-color:#E5B9B5;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Try adding `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` in the directive after the while loop.

Comment: @CodeHater is right. You will also need to inject `$compile` into the directive.

Comment: @CodeHater, I tried adding $compile(element.contents())(scope); but it's still not working

Comment: Just add `ng-app="app"` next to the `ng-controller` directive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the `$compile` service, since you are working in the `link` function inside the directive.

Once you hit the `link` function, the DOM is already built, and angular will not be aware of any changes you make to the DOM inside the `link` function, unless you run the changes through the `$compile` service.

Try this (untested):

```
app.directive('barsCurrent', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('value', function (newValue) {
                // value attribute has changed, re-render              
                var value = Number(newValue);
                var dval = value / 3;
                element.children().remove();
                while (dval > 0) {
                    var newDom = '<div id="bar" ng-class="{true: \'greater\',false: \'less\'}[charge.current >= charge.max]" style="float:left; color:green; height: 17px;margin-top:7px;background-color:green;">.</div>'
                    element.append($compile(newDom)(scope));
                    dval--;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Here's an example jsfiddle that uses `$compile` inside a directive `link` function:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/4YtLu/)

UPDATE:

Here is a jsfiddle with a few changes that may provide the results you want:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tphalp/jGvsW/)

UPDATE 2:

I updated the fiddle again. It should now be the result you want. Same fiddle, just updated. (Use link above).

Comment: Hi Tyson, still not working.. Do you think is it because it cannot detect the charge.current and charge.max inside the ng-class?

Comment: That could be. Your directive doesn't have isolate scope, so it should be able to see the scope vars from the parent scope. Is that where the `charge.current` and `charge.max` exist? 

I would try `console.log`ing them inside the directive link function, just to make sure they can be referenced by the directive.

Also, I'm not familiar with the manner in which you are using the `ng-class`, so I can't say whether or not that will work. If the logic inside the `ng-class` gets complex, I usually move it into a separate `scope` method.

Comment: the ng-class will only change the background-color of the div..that is if charge.current >= charge max, then it's avocado green else pink... I tried placing console.log inside the link function..however, i hit errors like charge undefined... and the entire barscurrent didn't work already

Comment: Maybe you could throw the code into a fiddle, or something similar?

Comment: Hi Tyson, how will I make it work in IE8? It seems to be not working in IE8

Comment: I already placed <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <script>
        document.createElement('bars-current');
      </script>
    <![endif]--> still doesn't work in IE8

Comment: Sorry, IE has never been a target browser for the work I do (desktop app built on top of Chromium Embedded Framework), as such, I've never had to deal with IE at all, nor do I have access to IE8 to test. Maybe check out the AngularJS docs on dealing with IE. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie